# Intent is sending back info blank

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm writing an app to take a survey and tally's the answers. The app has a default question "Do you like the Vikings", which works fine. I added in the feature to edit the question & buttons but now both are blank by default. Worse, no matter what I put in the edit activity, it stays blank!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private Button mYesButton;
    private Button mNoButton;
    private Button mResultsButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;
    private Button mEditButton;
    private TextView EditQuestion;
    private Button YesButtonEdit;
    private Button NoButtonEdit;

    int YesTimes;
    int NoTimes;


    public static final String EXTRA_EDIT_QUESTION = "com.example.surveyapp.EditActivity.edit_this_question";

    //private SurveryQuestion[] mQuestionBank = new SurveryQuestion[] {
        //      new SurveryQuestion(R.string.question_1),
        //      new SurveryQuestion()
        //};
    String[] mSurveyArray = {

        new String("hello"), //More questions coming soon!
        new String("Hello1"),
        //new String(R.string.question_1)
    };
    int mCurrentIndex = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mYesButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yes_button); //Yes/NoButton modified from LMGTFY app
        mYesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                        YesTimes += 1;
                        mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mSurveyArray.length;
                            // Coming soon!

            }
        });
        mNoButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.no_button);
        mNoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                NoTimes += 1;

            }
        });
        mResultsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.result_button);
        mResultsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //Here we make toast!
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), //Discovered getApplicationContext from stackoverflow
                    mYesButton + ": " + YesTimes + mNoButton + ": " + NoTimes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });

        mEditButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.edit_button); //This is the button that lets you edit the survey
        mEditButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditActivity.class); 
                startActivity(i); 






            }

        });


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String EditQuestion = intent.getStringExtra("sendBack");
        String YesButtonEdit = intent.getStringExtra("sendBack2");
        String NoButtonEdit = intent.getStringExtra("sendBack3");
        TextView mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view); 
        Button mYesButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yes_button);
        Button mNoButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.no_button);
        mQuestionTextView.setText(EditQuestion);
        mYesButton.setText(YesButtonEdit);
        mNoButton.setText(NoButtonEdit);





    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is the second activity where you add in your edited responses.

```
package com.example.surveyapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EditActivity extends Activity {
    private Button mCompleteButton;
    private EditText mEditText1;
    private EditText mEditText2;
    private EditText mEditText3;

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);




     mCompleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CompleteButton);
     mCompleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            EditText mEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText mEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            EditText mEditText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

            Intent i = new Intent(EditActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
            i.putExtra("SendBack", mEditText1.getText().toString()); //This is supposed to use EXTRA to send back the data
            i.putExtra("SendBack2", mEditText2.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("SendBack3", mEditText2.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);

        }

     });
     }
}
```

I've tried several approaches and I've gotten nothing. Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem might be that when you call `startActivity` with an intent to make a new `MainActivity`, android recognizes that there is already an instance of this activity, so it just brings it to the front.

One way to get around this would be to first make a public method that you can use to edit the fields in your `MainActivity`, and you can call this method just before you would like to send the user back to this activity from the edit activity. Also, instead of creating a new activity, just close the edit activity and android will resume the main activity.

If this doesn't work, post any logcat data you have from testing your app.

Answer (score 0):

For clean and clearer code, initialize all your button objects in the onCreate() method. Now try putting the following code in the onResume callback method like this

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
  super.onResume();
  Intent intent = getIntent();
        String EditQuestion = intent.getStringExtra("sendBack");
        String YesButtonEdit = intent.getStringExtra("sendBack2");
        String NoButtonEdit = intent.getStringExtra("sendBack3");
        TextView mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view); 
        Button mYesButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yes_button);
        Button mNoButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.no_button);
        mQuestionTextView.setText(EditQuestion);
        mYesButton.setText(YesButtonEdit);
        mNoButton.setText(NoButtonEdit);
}
```

remove this code from your onCreate(...) method and place it in your onResume method. When you clcik the edit button and want to get the data in the edit activity, do like so from the callling activity

```
 mEditButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.edit_button); //This is the button that lets you edit the survey
        mEditButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditActivity.class); 
                 i.putExtra("sendBack","send back value");
                 i.putExtra("sendBack2","send back 2 value");
                startActivity(i); 
            }
        });
```

with this, you should now be able to modify and pass in the values you wish to modify in your EditActivity

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Still didn't help. Well shoot =/